# Google driving API returns no results for valid geo coordinates

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to geo-route 2 Australian (victorian) addresses, if I use the string version of the address I get the results I am expecting, however if I use geo coordinates I get no results.

The url i generated is this...

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=145.159293,-37.810449&destination=144.970388,-37.799827&mode=driving
```

The structure appears correct to me, as this Url with UK addresess in the same structure does return results.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=53.21742417,-2.603484875&destination=53.0,-2.603484875&mode=driving
```

Edit:
Note the geo codes that are not returning results are equivalent to the following string based address which is returning results...

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=2%20heatherlea%20court%2C%20blackburn%20north%2C%20vic%2C%203130&destination=29%20Rathdown%20street%2C%20carlton%2C%20vic&mode=driving
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, dammit.

I Have the lattitude and longitude around the wrong way.